# iPhone Distribution certificate looks fine in Keychain but XCode claims valid signing identity not found

Tags: xcode, certificate, keychain

Like many people I'm having issues with the Distribution certificate from Apple, I've been able to include this in my Keychain Access without trouble and it shows up there fine.  When I try to check my Publishing Profiles in XCode I see the Distribution Profile show up as a valid signing identity not found.

I've deleted the profiles and recreated them, even removing my own Developer Profile and recreating it.  The Distribution Profile was created fine in the Provisioning Profile on the Apple site.  While I am not building the app through XCode, but through PhoneGap, I do still need to be able to Extract the certificates for PhoneGap's building process.

I've gone over all the steps on previous questions on this, I am running XCode 4.3.2 so I think I am past the bug with XCode not correctly signing the certificates.  I have deleted and recreated all my certificates in the login keychain.  About the only thing I notice now, and not sure what happened, is that the Distribution Profile shows up in the Keychain without a key, should it have one?  When I go to evaluate it I get no root cert found, but if I check the certificate I see its chain through the WDR certificate to the Apple Root CA.

I'd like to know if there is a way to verify what is the problem with the signing identity if I have gone through the steps to recreate the certificates?  What identity would be the problem?  Does the Distribution Profile install with a root cert if built from the Apple Site?  I feel like in many of the instructions I have missed a step but can't tell what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the certificates that we created were not compatible with the earlier 3rd party that did our work, and the PhoneGap service that was handling the builds.  Removing and recreating all from scratch is what finally did the trick, earlier I was not removing our initial certification since that was tied into the earlier third party work.